# Representation of a homogeneous Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given a homogeneous Poisson process $\{N(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ with intensity rate $\lambda>0$. Does someone know how to prove that there is a sequence of i.i.d. $Exp(\lambda)$-distributed random variables $(W_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the arrival times $T_n$ of this process can be represented by the sum $T_n=\sum_{j=1}^n W_j$?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $N(t)=0$, we have
$$T_1 = \inf\{t\geqslant 0: N(t)=1\}. $$
So for any $t>0$, $T_1>t$ iff $N(t)=0$. Hence
$$\mathbb P(T_1>t) = \mathbb P(N(t)=0)=e^{-\lambda t}. $$
Set $W_1=T_1$, then $W_1\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$. If $n>1$ then
$$T_n = T_1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} T_{j+1}-T_j. $$
Let $W_{j+1}=T_{j+1}-T_j$ for $j\geqslant 1$. Then $W_j$ has the desired property. As for any $t>0$, $T_{j+1}-T_j>t$ iff $T_{j+1}>t+T_j$ iff $N(t+T_j)-N(T_j)=0$. By stationary increments, we have
$$\mathbb P(N(t+T_j)-N(T_j)=0)=\mathbb P(N(t)=0)=e^{-\lambda t}, $$
so that $T_{j+1}-T_j\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$. The independence of the $W_j$ follows from $N(t)$ having independent increments.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is only one (technical) thing that is not clear to me: For proving that the $W_j$ are iid you use the "stationary/independent increments"-property of the Poisson process for the stopping times $T_j$. Why do these properties carry over when one plugs in random times?

Comment: It's valid precisely because the $T_j$ are stopping times, i.e. for any $t>0$, $\mathbb P(T_j\leqslant t)\in\sigma(\{N(s):s\leqslant t\})$.